# Turning an unsafe state into a safe state - Banker's Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I have included an example in my question. I know this state is unsafe as there are no full sequences in the process. However, is there a way to arrive at a safe state from it at all?
[image]

Comment: The only possible way to arrive at a safe state from that unsafe state is for some processes to return some of the resources that have been allocated to them before they get hold of all resources they would like to claim. For example, $P_1$ returns all its resources now. Does this answer your question?